# Can I travel to the US without holding a job?

Tags: visas, usa, italian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I live in Italy and I was wondering if I can apply for a tourist visa even if I don't have a job?

I enroll at collegio dei geometri in Udine Italy.

I have to take an exam in 2020 so I can become a quantity surveyor and start a job. I have my two brothers in the US who are US citizen and my dad is a is permanent resident. My stepmother is a citizen too. Can they help me for my application to go and visit them?

I already applied for US tourist visa but it was denied because I was a green card holder with an expired resident. Now I'm no longer a green card holder and would like to apply for another visa to go and visit my family.

Comment: You need to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent. That might be difficult with your immigration history and family in the US. Possible duplicate of [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: I thought green cards had no expiration date (I mean, every 5 or 10 years they were automatically / manually renewed)

Comment: @JuanCa if the green card holder has abandoned residence in the US in fact, but not declared as much administratively, I believe the consular service won't issue a visa, though the normal procedure would be, I think, to process the relinquishment of permanent residence rather than denying the application.

Comment: @Traveller someone who has abandoned permanent residence seems rather more likely to be able to demonstrate a lack of immigrant intent, don't you think?

Comment: @phoog Good point - unless they’ve changed their mind :-)

Comment: Estefany, as an Italian citizen, you don't need a visa.  Why did you apply for one?  Are you perhaps confusing "visa" with "ESTA"?  How did you relinquish your green card?  What reason was given for the refusal of your earlier visa?

Comment: The citizen tag was added by the editor of the question, not the asker. So that would be the first thing to clarify. "Living in " doesn't necessarily mean "being a citizen of".

Comment: According to [Passport index](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=it&fl=&s=yes), italian passports have "eTA / 90 days" to USA.

Comment: @JuanCa yep, that's ESTA.

Comment: Since your green card expired, you may want to read this similar question about re-entry: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42045/can-the-us-still-be-entered-on-a-tourist-visa-after-permanent-resident-status-is

Comment: My suggestion is to bring proof of your university enrollment, so that if you are stopped and question during entry as a tourist, you can show that you have reason to return to Italy.